Customize column headings in results of SearchKit
How can I customize the column headings (aliases) in the results of a SearchKit search?  The column names are sometimes very long and non-intuitive for my end users, especially when you join with 2-3 tables.

Welcome to the Civicrm forum!
You can customize the search results by creating a "search display" of type Table. Then you can sort the results, rename the column headings, enable in table edit and other cool things.
Here's a screenshot of how to do that when editing your SearchKit search in CiviCRM 5.72.1


Thanks Justin657.  That worked.  I'm only on CiviCRM 5.72.1 and the one issue I noticed after creating the custom table is that the Details column (contact notes) is displaying raw HTML with visible  tags.  I tried every combination of checkboxes on the column form to no avail.  I'm guessing this is fixed in the latest release.

Ticking the "Allow HTML" checkbox on your Details (Contact Note > Note) field should do the trick. It works for me on 5.72.1 when testing with ,  and  tags.

You can always test new features or compare your installation to a stock CiviCRM installation using the demos provided here: https://civicrm.org/demo
Look especially at the bottom of the page under Testing Sandboxes for a stock system similar to yours. Then you can test your desired feature there.

Doesn't work on my version of Civi but thanks for the tip on testing on a demo site!
